# Input string was not in a correct formatt asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string query = "select * from tblUser where UEmail = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = obj.fillDataset(query);

if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int pwd = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UPassword"].ToString());
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("somemailaddress@gmail.com", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
    msg.Subject = "Confirm Password";
    msg.Body = "Your password is" + pwd.ToString();
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    NetworkCredential ntwcred = new NetworkCredential();
    ntwcred.UserName = "somemailaddress@gmail.com";
    ntwcred.Password = "********";
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = ntwcred;
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Send(msg);
    Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Your Password is Successfully sent to your Email');</script>");
}
```

I am applying functionality that when user enters his email address in a textbox and clicks a button, an email is sent to the email address, so he can get his forgotten password.

I am getting an error on the line below:

```
int pwd = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UPassword"].ToString());
```

(the password datatype is `varchar` in sqlserver)

Comment: Use parameterized queries please. And hash your passwords

Comment: you're trying to convert password text to integer.... which doesn't work.

Comment: Is the password composed of digits only ?!

Comment: no sir have character also

Comment: So why are you trying to parse it into an int?

Comment: I'll throw in another suggestion. When you send an email, you don't know if it will succeed in certain situations (such as the target email address doesn't exist). For this reason you really should be queuing these requests up somewhere persistent (such as a database) and then sending them on a schedule. That way you can find all the requests that don't succeed and investigate why.

Comment: Really, *really* use parameterized SQL. That should be the *very, very* first thing you do, before you change *anything* about your code. Broken code (that fails quickly) is safer than vulnerable code.

Answer (score 0):

If the password can contain non-numeric characters, then don't try to convert it to an integer:

```
string pwd = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UPassword"];
```